# Can't log description of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary with one to four objects in it. Each of the contained objects is  an NSDictionary. The first dictionary contains about 83,000 references to NSManagedObjects. The second dictionary contains about 14,000 of the same types of objects.

In the code below, Nothing happens in the NSLog statement. It's as if it is skipped, and the program continues to run. However, I am having other problems with these dictionaries soon afterward. I thought clearing this one up first might shed some light on the rest of the problems.

```
pos = @"v";
NSLog(@"%@", pos);
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SYNSET" inManagedObjectContext:[ManagedObjectContext moc]]];
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"partOfSpeech = %@", pos];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"synsetOffset" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
synsetsArrayForPos = [[ManagedObjectContext moc] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
synsetDictionaryMutableForPos = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:100000];
for (SYNSET *synset in synsetsArrayForPos)
    [synsetDictionaryMutableForPos setObject:synset forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",synset.synsetOffset]];
[dictionaryMutableOfSynsetDictionaries setObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:synsetDictionaryMutableForPos] forKey:pos];

NSLog(@"dictionaryMutableOfSynsetDictionaries is class of %@ with description %@", [dictionaryMutableOfSynsetDictionaries class], [dictionaryMutableOfSynsetDictionaries description]);

pos = @"a";
NSLog(@"%@", pos);
```

I repeat this code four times wiht different values for `pos`, and each time, the NSLog that prints the description of the top level `dictionaryMutableOfSynsetDictionaries` dictionary fails to print. If I replace `[dictionaryMutableOfSynsetDictionaries description]' with a string constant, it prints.

What is happening here? Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

(This code, with the large dictionaries, is being used to finish the relationship links of a large sqlite database, and it would not be used in deployable code. I'm running it on the iOS simulator only. I'll put the updated database in my app bundle once this update is done.)

Answer (score 0):

Now I see what might be happening, but it doesn't completely answer why it isn't printed to the console.

The description method for NSDictionary returns a string that represents the contents of the dictionary, formatted as a property list. For such a large dictionary, it would log the entire contents, which is on the order of 100,000 records.

When I do `po [[dictionaryMutableOfSynsetDictionaries description] substringToIndex:1000]` it will show the first 1000 characters. If I don't shorten it this way, it takes a while to compose the string and then it takes forever to present to the console.

I did confirm, with log statements before and after the problem line, that the log statement in my question is not printing, while the before and after logs are printed. So  NSLog is throwing this away, I think.

Comment: I think I had a similar problem with NSLog just seemingly discarding very long strings — I didn't ever bother to check further, but it's good to see I'm not the only one with this problem. Although perhaps it's the console not handling such long strings, though?

Comment: The console seems to handle it if you use the `po` command. But it takes a very long time to present, in this case.